# Add a dropdown menu in a table with Reflex Python

Tags: python, menu, reflex, pynecone

I'm trying to add a dropdown menu to each row in a table with the use of reflex https://reflex.dev/. The table is build in a state and buttons generally in definitions. This is an example that can be found on their site:

```
class DataEditorState_HP(rx.State):
    clicked_data: str = "Cell clicked: "

    cols: list[Any] = [
        {"title": "Title", "type": "str"},
        {
            "title": "Name",
            "type": "str",
            "group": "Data",
            "width": 300,
        },
        {
            "title": "Birth",
            "type": "str",
            "group": "Data",
            "width": 150,
        },
        {
            "title": "Human",
            "type": "bool",
            "group": "Data",
            "width": 80,
        },
        {
            "title": "House",
            "type": "str",
            "group": "Data",
        },
        {
            "title": "Wand",
            "type": "str",
            "group": "Data",
            "width": 250,
        },
        {
            "title": "Patronus",
            "type": "str",
            "group": "Data",
        },
        {
            "title": "Blood status",
            "type": "str",
            "group": "Data",
            "width": 200,
        },
    ]

    data = [
        [
            "1",
            "Harry James Potter",
            "31 July 1980",
            True,
            "Gryffindor",
            "11'  Holly  phoenix feather",
            "Stag",
            "Half-blood",
        ],
        [
            "2",
            "Ronald Bilius Weasley",
            "1 March 1980",
            True,
            "Gryffindor",
            "12' Ash unicorn tail hair",
            "Jack Russell terrier",
            "Pure-blood",
        ],
        [
            "3",
            "Hermione Jean Granger",
            "19 September, 1979",
            True,
            "Gryffindor",
            "10¾'  vine wood dragon heartstring",
            "Otter",
            "Muggle-born",
        ],
        [
            "4",
            "Albus Percival Wulfric Brian Dumbledore",
            "Late August 1881",
            True,
            "Gryffindor",
            "15' Elder Thestral tail hair core",
            "Phoenix",
            "Half-blood",
        ],
        [
            "5",
            "Rubeus Hagrid",
            "6 December 1928",
            False,
            "Gryffindor",
            "16'  Oak unknown core",
            "None",
            "Part-Human (Half-giant)",
        ],
        [
            "6",
            "Fred Weasley",
            "1 April, 1978",
            True,
            "Gryffindor",
            "Unknown",
            "Unknown",
            "Pure-blood",
        ],
    ]

    def click_cell(self, pos):
        col, row = pos
        yield self.get_clicked_data(pos)

    def get_clicked_data(self, pos) -> str:
        self.clicked_data = f"Cell clicked: {pos}"

def index():
    return rx.data_editor(
    columns=DataEditorState_HP.cols,
    data=DataEditorState_HP.data,
    on_cell_clicked=DataEditorState_HP.click_cell,
)
```

It creates the table that is attached. I now want to change the House column to having a dropdown menu every row where if you click the cell, it will show the options Gryffindor, Huffelpuf, Ravenclaw and Slytherin. If you click one of them that name shows up in the table. This is the code that represents the dropdown menu:

```
rx.menu(
    rx.menu_button("Menu"),
    rx.menu_list(
        rx.menu_item("Example"),
        rx.menu_divider(),
        rx.menu_item("Example"),
        rx.menu_item("Example"),
    ),
)
```

What confuses me is that the rx only seems to be usable in a definition and not in a state, but the table exists in the state. How do I solve this?

I tried to add the menu in the state, but I get an error.